# What's the best way to delete a QNetworkReply?

Tags: c++, qt, rest, qt5

I'm writing an embedded RESTful API client using the Qt5 Embedded layer of OpenEmbedded project. I want my client to be able to send a simple async request to notify my server on what's going on and an other scenario is that my client needs to synchronize data from the server.

To do so I wrote two functions, one to send the request and another to get the response. So if I don't care about the response, I only use the first one.

To be able to use the response with the second one, I use a QNetworkReply * as a member of my class. To keep the QNetworkReply alive, I also set the QNetworkAccessManager as a member of my class.

```
#include <QtNetwork>

class ApiClient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    ApiClient(QObject *parent = 0);

private:

    QString host;
    QString key;
    quint32 replyTimeout;
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply;

    void sendRequest(const QString &method, const QVariantMap &params = QVariantMap());
    QVariantMap getResponse() const;
};
```

The apiclient.cpp file:

```
#include "apiclient.h"

ApiClient::ApiClient(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void ApiClient::sendRequest(const QString &method, const QVariantMap &params)
{
    QUrl url(QString("%1/%2/").arg(host).arg(method));

    QUrlQuery query;
    query.addQueryItem("key", key);

    if (!params.empty())
    {
        QMapIterator<QString, QVariant> it(params);
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            it.next();
            query.addQueryItem(it.key(), it.value().toString());
        }
    }

    url.setQuery(query);
    qDebug() << "url: " << url.toString();

    reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

QVariantMap ApiClient::getResponse() const
{
    if (!reply)
    {
        qFatal("No request sent!");
    }

    QTimer timer;
    timer.setSingleShot(true);

    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    timer.start(replyTimeout);
    loop.exec();

    if (timer.isActive())
    {
        timer.stop();

        if (reply->error())
        {
            qFatal("Wrong reply!");
        }

        int code = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
        if (code != 200)
        {
            qFatal("Invalid server response!");
        }

        QJsonDocument result = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());

        if (result.isNull())
        {
            qFatal("Invalid JSON!");
        }

        reply->deleteLater();
        return result.object().toVariantMap();
    }

    disconnect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    reply->abort();
    reply->deleteLater();
    return QVariantMap();
}
```

Is that a good way to proceed? How should I manage the QNetworkReply pointer when other signals are emitted (i.e. error(), sslErrors(), ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QNetworkReply` will always emit `finished()`, even when an error occured.

`deleteLater()` could even be called in a slot connected to that signal, so that part should be fine.

But I would recommend to look into a more asynchronous approach of handling the request, nested event loops like the on in your `getResponse()` can lead to "interesting" behavior, because you can basically get into re-entrancy situations in a single threaded program.

Comment: Is there a way to manage multiple QNetworkReply to avoid this issue?

Comment: Each all to one of the request methods will return a new network reply object and some of the manager's signals even have the pointer to the respective reply as ana argument, e.g. `QNetworkAccessManager::finished()`.
Alternatively you can use `QObject::sender()` in slots connected to reply signals to find which of many replies has signalled something. 
Another option is to have individual reply handler objects for each reply, basically having one signal receiver instance per reply

Comment: OK I'll use `QNetworkAccessManager::finished(QNetworkReply *)` thanks.